# How can translate the data from database in another language? Odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10, translate

Select the data from the database. Selected data is coming without translation. Because the data.xml file is written in English.
I would like to choose the language selected by the login language.
Is that possible?
Here is a some code:

```
account_obj = self.env['account.name']
        acc_template2 = account_obj.search([('parent_id', '!=', False)], order='code')
        for template in acc_template2:
            vals = {'name': template.name}#this value
            print vals
```

The result:

```
{'name': u'Some text'}
```

I'm using Odoo10.0 The .po file has been translated into "account.name". Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried it. But I think that you should translate template.name strings in your_language.po and reload and overwrite your language file in Settings -> Translation (Odoo 12).

[image: screenshot]

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _

translated_name = _(vals.name)
```

Try like above. It might help.

Also this might help: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-translate-content-of-text-fields-from-records-108632

Comment: Thank's for your advice. I'm tried, but not working.

Comment: @С.Дэлгэрцэцэг have you tried the `translate=True` flag as suggested in link above? You should inherit from original template model and override this field if the original is not translatable.